# How can Rex take multiple hits from blaster bolts?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In season 3 episode 6, Rex is shown taking multiple hits

> from battle droids

one to his shoulder, and one to his helmet.  In the *Clone Wars* TV show, when a clone trooper is shot, they go down.  Even if they are just wounded and not dead, we definitely don’t see any troopers getting shot in the head and getting right back up.  There wasn’t even any carbon scoring on Rex’s armor/helmet. Furthermore, Rex was shot in the shoulder right where there is a chink in his armor. I could understand Rex surviving those hits, but there should have at least been holes in his armor where he got shot.

The only explanation I can think of is that

> the droid’s blasters had lost power over time.

Is there any explanation of how Rex could have survived, or is this just another case of main characters never dying?

Comment: [Plot armour](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotArmor)

Comment: @Valorum "Magnetic" shielding on the helmet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question was answered by Pablo Hidalgo, a member of the Lucasfilm Story Group, on the *Star Wars Rebels* after show called *Rebels Recon* for the episode succeeding this one, titled "Imperial Super Commandos." According to him, the reason why Rex survived being shot so many times is the same reason that you thought:

> What we're dealing with is battle droid equipment that is subpar and has gone to waste and droidekas that aren't at full power. So, if those things were fresh and new, Rex's number could have been up, but thankfully they were pretty out run.
>
> <sub>[*Rebels Recon: Inside "Imperial Super Commandos"*](https://www.starwars.com/video/rebels-recon-inside-imperial-super-commandos)</sub>